# Mysql execution time is too long

Tags: mysql

I have 2 millions record in my table. when i execute a query that has 3 `where condition` it takes too long to response.

**query** :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM `table` 
 WHERE DATE(`created_at`) = '2017-08-11' 
   AND `type` in (4,13,15) 
   AND `status` = 1
```

**execution time** : 3 seconds

how can i reduce the execution time of this query or any query like this?

***Edit***

**Table schema** :

```
CREATE TABLE `transactions` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `type` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2',
  `created_at` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `query` (`created_at`,`type`,`status`),
  KEY `query2` (`status`,`type`)
```

I don't know my indexing is true or not

Comment: how does your table look like? I think you're missing a few `index`es

Comment: @Fotis it has 41 column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try separating the `IN` clause. I have personally experienced `IN` clause making queries slow as internally `MySQL` assumes full table scan and ignores the index in certain situations. Also, DATE(`created_at`) will ignore the index completely as it's indexed on datetime.

You can try below `UNION` query and hope it speeds up the output:

```
SELECT SUM(total) AS total
  FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM `table` 
    WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN '2017-08-11 00:00:00' AND  '2017-08-11 23:59:59'
      AND `type` = 4 
      AND `status` = 1
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM `table` 
    WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN '2017-08-11 00:00:00' AND  '2017-08-11 23:59:59'
      AND `type` = 13 
      AND `status` = 1
    UNION
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS total
      FROM `table` 
    WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN '2017-08-11 00:00:00' AND  '2017-08-11 23:59:59'
      AND `type` = 15 
      AND `status` = 1
  ) z;
```

You can also add a column that contains only `date` or remove time from `created_at` and store it in a new `time` column, if feasible for your existing system.

Comment: i have syntax error on ``(DATE(`created_at`),`type`,`status`)``

Comment: sorry my bad. Busy at work so replied in a hurry. Didn't notice the index error. Have updated my post. Do not alter your index. Have modified the query. Try it out.

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to make this query run faster, you need to add indexes to your table.

First of all run the same query by adding `EXPLAIN` before your `SELECT`. This will give you a nice overview of how many rows were examined, what's the key cardinality etc.

If this is a standard query you're using, I suggest you [add an index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) for all 3 columns. If you plan to query the columns separately, you can add an index to each column you need to query, but don't overdo it as the table will become slower.

If you run `EXPLAIN` after you've added the indexes you'd get a significantly lower count of rows examined I guess.

If your table already has indexes, you can hint the MySQL server by using a [`USE INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html) hint.

Answer (score 0):

could be you need  a proper index eg:

```
  create index  my_new_index on `table`  ( date(`created_at`), `type`,  `status` );
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace

KEY `query` (`created_at`,`type`,`status`),

KEY `query2` (`status`,`type`),

with

KEY `created_at` (`created_at`),

KEY `type` (`type`),

KEY `status` (`status`),

I think it will make faster. Also you have to chage datatype of type and status to tinyint, smallint, if it's possible and unsigned constraint should be added it's never signed value.